# Storyboard issue: Gesture recognisers cannot be used on prototype objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I suddenly started to get this error on my project:
Gesture recognisers cannot be used on prototype objects.
I seems like an error in my StoryBoard. It might have stated after I upgraded to: Xcode 5.1

Does anyone know what it means? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Thanks, it is probably a duplicate. But my problem now is: I just started getting this error and have no way of removing it. How can I fix this error? Xcode doesn't tell me where exactly the issue in the storyboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by locating all the places in my StoryBoard for which I connected TapGestureRecognizer directly to a control that was inside a custom UITableViewCell. This is strange, because in Xcode 5 it used to work and suddenly started screaming in Xcode 5.1.